# Adding custom markers to lcjs chart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Please find attached image with highlighted markers. Is this functionality possible with arction lightning chart js. Chart needs to have the ability to draw multiple custom vertical lines and on moving custom lines the marker highlighted in yellow needs to update its position and delta value.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part should be functionally possible.

The vertical lines (red, blue, green, etc.) with **ConstantLine**s.

API: https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/constantline.html

Example: https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0701-bandsConstantlines.html?theme=darkGold&page-theme=dark

The horizontal lines with **SegmentSeries**. Note that dashed line style is not available as of yet.

API: https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/segmentseries.html

Texts inside series area with **UITextBox**es.

Example (UI positioned in axis coordinates): https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0026-temperatureAnomalyChart.html?theme=darkGold&page-theme=dark

[image]

If this is for a commercial use case I would strongly suggest leaving a general inquiry at our [web site](https://lightningchart.com/contact/). I will not be clarifying or extending this answer in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . I was able to add this after following the example links you provided