# How to get the value of Point when Adding custom markers to lcjs chart

Tags: lightningchart

I'm trying to use a constant line to mark values, but I don't know how to get the value corresponding to the curve it intersects.

the same with this question:[Adding custom markers to lcjs chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111465/adding-custom-markers-to-lcjs-chart)

```
const chart = lightningChart()
    .ChartXY({
        theme: Themes.darkGold,
    })
const series = chart.addLineSeries().setName('Y1')
createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
    .setNumberOfPoints(100)
    .generate()
    .toPromise()
    .then((data) => {
        series.add(data)
    })
const xAxis = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
const xAxisConstantline = xAxis.addConstantLine()
xAxisConstantline.setValue(100)
xAxisConstantline.setName('X Axis Constantline')
```

how to get the value of Y1 in xAxisConstantline value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a line series with some data, and you know a coordinate on X axis, and want to know the respective Y coordinate on the line series?

This can be done using `LineSeries.solveNearestFromScreen`

Please see custom cursor chart example for immediate reference:

https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0702-customCursor.html?isList=false